# How to have c++ 20 on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, execution, mingw-w64, gcc9

I am working on windows 10 and currently have gcc8 installed on my system but the thing is `#include <execution>` cannot work with this version of gcc. So, I want to have gcc 9, but I have downloaded mingw 8 (the newest version) which probably have the latest gcc.

But this version of mingw does not have an installer. I copied on my driver but I am stuck the path I have to add to my system variables. since, there is no bin including lost of exes.
Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: There is gcc10.2 available in msys2

Comment: C++20 compiler support is still under development, here is [list of supported features](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B20_library_features) you can use to select compiler. At the end you have to check compiler documentation to see what it supports and what not yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use msvc which supports c++20 features

[image]

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B20_library_features

Comment: I've fixed missing link. Posting only this picture is not helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/#installation). It contains mingw and comes with a gcc 10.2.

Msys further comes with the package manager `pacman`, so there is no need to manually download and install packages.

Also when there is an updated gcc, it will soon appear in the repository and can be installed with pacman update (see the link for details).

Comment: Great! worked .MYSYS2 was amazing! now, I have gcc 10 on my windows

Comment: I am glad the anwer helped you. Please accept it when the issue is resolved.